React Native WebView: Issues with Google Sign-In and Cloudflare Protection
"React Native WebView: Issues with Google Sign-In and Cloudflare Protection"
Hello,
I am working on a React Native project using Expo and react-native-webview to load my app's website. However, I am encountering two main issues:
Google Sign-In Issue: When I attempt to log in using Google, I see the following error:
"Couldn't sign you in: This browser or app may not be secure."
(See the attached screenshot below for reference.)
Cloudflare Blocking: On certain pages, Cloudflare protection triggers, and the WebView is unable to bypass it.
My Code:
Here is the code I am using for the WebView:
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Platform, StatusBar, BackHandler } from 'react-native';
import { WebView, WebViewNavigation } from 'react-native-webview';
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';
import ControlInternet from './components/ControlInternet';

SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [ready, setReady] = useState(false);
  const [webKey, setWebKey] = useState(0);
  const webViewRef = useRef<WebView>(null);
  const [canGoBack, setCanGoBack] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const initializeApp = async () => {
      await SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

      setTimeout(async () => {
        await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
      }, 2000);
    };

    initializeApp();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const backAction = () => {
      if (canGoBack && webViewRef.current) {
        webViewRef.current.goBack(); 
        return true; 
      }
      return false; 
    };

    const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
      'hardwareBackPress',
      backAction
    );

    return () => backHandler.remove();
  }, [canGoBack]);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar barStyle={Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'default' : 'default'} />
      <ControlInternet>
        <WebView
          key={webKey}
          ref={webViewRef}
          source={{ uri: 'https://www.example.com/' }}
          userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          cacheEnabled={false}
          cacheMode={'LOAD_NO_CACHE'}
          incognito={true}
          javaScriptEnabled={true}
          bounces={false}
          automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
          scalesPageToFit={false}
          onLoadEnd={() => {
            if (!ready) {
              setWebKey(Date.now());
              setReady(true);
            }
          }}
          onNavigationStateChange={(navState: WebViewNavigation) => {
            setCanGoBack(navState.canGoBack);
          }}
        />
      </ControlInternet>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
});

export default App;

What I've Tried:
Changed the userAgent string to emulate different browsers.
Enabled thirdPartyCookiesEnabled and mixedContentMode.
Tried disabling incognito mode.
Used a proxy server to bypass Cloudflare, but it didn't resolve the issue.
Checked for any additional headers or configurations required for Google Sign-In.
Questions:
How can I resolve the "Couldn't sign you in" issue when using Google Sign-In in a WebView?
Is there a way to bypass Cloudflare protection for WebView, or do I need a different approach?
thanks for help
google login
